# How to do a "real concurrent" corroutines

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm trying to do this:

"An event loop runs in a thread (typically the main thread) and executes all callbacks and Tasks in its thread. While a Task is running in the event loop, no other Tasks can run in the same thread. **When a Task executes an await expression, the running Task gets suspended, and the event loop executes the next Task**."

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading

And I did this ugly example:

```
import asyncio

async def print_message(message):
    print(message)

async def int_sum(a, b):
    await print_message('start_sum')
    result = a + b
    await print_message('end_sum')
    return result

async def int_mul(a, b):
    await print_message('start_mul')
    result = a * b
    await print_message('end_mul')
    return result

async def main():
    result = await asyncio.gather(int_sum(4, 3), int_mul(4, 3))
    print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

With "secuential-like" results:

```
$ python async_test.py

start_sum
end_sum
start_mul
end_mul
[7, 12]
```

But I want a "corroutine-like" output:

```
$ python async_test.py

start_sum
start_mul
end_sum
end_mul
[7, 12]
```

How can I do that?

**Note**: I'm not looking for a `asyncio.sleep(n)` example, I'm looking for
"When a Task executes an await expression, the running Task gets suspended, and the event loop executes the next Task".

Comment: if you want the tasks to run in parallel, then you need `multiprocessing` and not `asyncio`...

Comment: Note: I'm not looking for a "asyncio.sleep(n)" example, I'm looking for "When a Task executes an await expression, the running Task gets suspended, and the event loop executes the next Task"......  but this is the purpose of `asyncio` !

Comment: @D.L thanks for the comment. Yep, I know, that's the asyncio purpose, maybe I don't undestand the output. I expect an output like:
"start_sum  # firstone task await ; 
start_mul  # then the sencondone task await ; 
end_sum  # the firstone task next await ; 
end_mul  # Finally the secondone task next await". 

But it doesn't happens and I don't undestand why.

Comment: the three cmmon options that you have are `multiprocessing`, `threading` and `asyncio`....  if you want them to be independent, then its `multiprocessing`.  The alternatives are `threading` and `asyncio` which is like user controlled threading.  So it depends on what you want to do.....  hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is, Tasks only give the control back to the event loop with `yield` statement. In your example you already have three active tasks(add `asyncio.all_tasks()` in the first line of `int_sum` coroutine to confirm<sup>1</sup>) but for example `int_sum` is not cooperating. it doesn't give the control back to the event loop. why ? Because you don't have any `yield`.

A simple fix to this is to change your `print_message` to:

```py
async def print_message(message):
    print(message)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

if you see the source code of [`asyncio.sleep`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L632):

```py
async def sleep(delay, result=None):
    """Coroutine that completes after a given time (in seconds)."""
    if delay <= 0:
        await __sleep0()
        return result
...
```

And this is the body of the `__sleep0()`(right above the `sleep`):

```py
@types.coroutine
def __sleep0():
    """Skip one event loop run cycle.

    This is a private helper for 'asyncio.sleep()', used
    when the 'delay' is set to 0.  It uses a bare 'yield'
    expression (which Task.__step knows how to handle)
    instead of creating a Future object.
    """
    yield
```

Now your output should be:

```
start_sum
start_mul
end_sum
end_mul
[7, 12]
```

<sup>1</sup> **Note:** you *do* have three tasks, [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) does that for you:

> If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled
> as a Task.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did a function "@types.coroutine; def next_task(): yield" and I used it in print_message just to check it. But, have the sleep or the "next_task" sense in a production code? Do you know if it is a bad practice? Thanks

Comment: @Rubén No It isn't considered bad practice, when you need to force an async function to yield control to event loop, it's a valid option. But don't create additional `next_task` for yourself, you simply don't need it, it's already defined in asyncio framework.